# Docker Compose Wait for MySQL Container to be Ready

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I am using Docker for "FROM node:17-alpine". docker-compose wait for MySQL container to be ready before starting a dependent docker api container.

I try to use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) but It does not run on node alpine.

May I know how to wait api container until db container is up and running.

Comment: You should be able to use the node socket module to just check the database port is open

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using something like https://github.com/raphaelahrens/wait-for-it, it uses `nc` so it will probably work on alpine linux.
if not then there is the option of running https://github.com/ettore26/wait-for-command
with the arguments
`./wait-for-command.sh -c 'nc -z db 5432' && [your-after-the-wait-commands]`
just change **5432** for your mysql port

Comment: I use docker compose wait as follow 
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.5.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
CMD /wait && yarn start:migrate:prod